# Замена текстуры в three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl

Подскажите, пожалуйста. Пытаюсь разобраться как с помощью threejs можно получить в консоль все элементы загруженного объекта в формате GLTF, для последующей замены текстур по нажатию кнопки.

```
var scene, camera, renderer, ambientLight, light;

var w = 1920;
var h = 1080;
var fullWidth = w * 3;
var fullHeight = h * 2;



scene = new THREE.Scene();
scene.background = new THREE.Color(0x616161);

camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(32, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight,1,5000);
camera.position.set(45, 90, 120);
camera.setViewOffset( fullWidth, fullHeight, w * 1, h * 0.5, w, h );

light = new THREE.SpotLight(0xffffff,1);
light.position.set(-50,50,50);
light.castShadow = true;
light.shadow.bias = -0.0001;
light.shadow.mapSize.width = 1024*4;
light.shadow.mapSize.height = 1024*4;
scene.add( light );

renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true;

document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
renderer.gammaOutput = true;
// var light = new THREE.HemisphereLight( 0xdbdbdb, 0x363636, 0.8 );
// scene.add( light );


var controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
controls.update();

var abint = new THREE.AmbientLight(0x5c5c5c);
scene.add(abint);

var loader = new THREE.GLTFLoader();

loader.load( 'models/box_model/scene.gltf', function ( gltf ) {
    gltf.scene.scale.set(14,14,14);
    scene.add( gltf.scene );

    //model = result.scene.children[0]; 
    model.position.set(0,-5,-25);
    model.traverse(n => { if ( n.isMesh ) {
      n.castShadow = true; 
      n.receiveShadow = true;
      if(n.material.map) n.material.map.anisotropy = 1; 
    }});
    scene.add(model);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Для того, чтобы получить список всех мешей модели в консоли, callback функция загрузчика должна бы выглядеть так:

```js
var model;
var modelParts = [];
loader.load( 'models/box_model/scene.gltf', function ( gltf ) {
    
    model = gltf.scene;
    model.scale.set(14,14,14);

    model.position.set(0,-5,-25);
    model.traverse(n => { if ( n.isMesh ) {
      n.castShadow = true; 
      n.receiveShadow = true;
      if(n.material.map) n.material.map.anisotropy = 1;
      modelParts.push(n); 
    }});
    console.log(modelParts);
    scene.add(model);
});
```

Comment: Спасибо большое. А для замены текстуры использовать TextureLoader?

Comment: @AnatoliyC В общем и целом - да. TextureLoader используется за загрузки текстур.